# Loss of data converting a UInt64 to float in C#

Tags: c#

I am attempting to do some mat on two UInt64 values and store the result in a float:

```
UInt64 val64 = 18446744073709551615;
UInt64 val64_2 = 18446744073709551000;

float val = (float)val64 - val64_2;
Console.WriteLine(val64);
Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("f"));

Console.ReadKey();
```

I am expecting the val to be 615.0 but instead I am getting 0.0!
Using double instead for val seems to work but surely float is capable of storing 615.0. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `float val = (float)(val64 - val64_2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the result that is being truncated, it's the values used in the calculation. You are casting `val64` to a `float` in your sum. This also means `val64_2` will be cast to a float (to match val64). Both have lost enough precision that they are the same value when represted as a float, and the difference is 0.

You want to keep them as `UInt64` for the subtraction, and have the result as a float. i.e.

```
float val = (float)(val64 - val64_2);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `18446744073709551615` be able to be represented by `float` without truncation?

Comment: @RGraham `float` in .Net is 7 digits of precision.

Comment: But isn't this an integer? Says on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) the range is -3.4 × 10^38 to +3.4 × 10^38

Comment: Range and precision are not the same thing. `18446744073709551615`  as a float is stored as `1.844674 x 10^19`, exactly the same as it would be for `18446744073709551000`

Comment: Got it. Thanks for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 0):

Float is an approximation that can store only 6 or 7 significant digits (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd7199ke.aspx)

In your code both UInt64s end up as 1.84467441E+19 when cast to float.

As various people have already mentioned the solution is to keep the values as UInt64s for the subtraction.